# SQL Server BCP not accepting pipe | field terminator in format file

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I'm creating a BCP IN process to load a pipe delimited file into a table.  The BCP utility gives me the error ***Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Syntax error at line 4 column 51 in xml format file*** when it runs.  The first rows of the format file are as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <RECORD>
        <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="|", MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" />
```

The location of the error is right at the "|" of the FIELD entry.  I have tried various variations of single and double quotes, no quotes and slash in front of and around the pipe, but the error is always thrown at the same spot.

The file itself is just multiple rows of data with a pipe delimiter and short header/trailer records at the top and bottom of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is the issue but the comma after the terminator attribute doesn't look right

TERMINATOR="|"**,**

Comment: Yep, it was the comma.  Thanks.  So used to fields/attributes in T-SQL always being separated by commas, apparently it's just an automatic thing in my head.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell from the question, but if this has something to do with Command windows, batch files, and/or not-so-subtle flat file manipulation, you may be being hit by the fact that the pipe character has a very specific use. There are a number of obscure ways to "escape" special characters in these environments... and while I never found any solid documentation back when I was fighting that fight, over time I determined that using one or a combination of quotes, ^, and & would often solve my problems. For example, you might *carefully* try the following:

```
<FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="^|", MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" />

<FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="&|", MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" />
```

Of course it might just be @Conrads comma problem, in which case ignore all this.

Comment: you are genius. i was struggling to generate format file with custom delimiter and your answer worked... Thanks!!!!